# PhpStorm - show detailed doctag infos

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.3

In NetBeans we can show detailed infos about declarations if we hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hover the mouse over the function name.

[image]

How does this work in PhpStorm?
I only get few infos on PhpStorm:

[image: Php]

I only get more infos if I click on the function link in the yellow box which you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general -- just place caret on the element you are interested in (function/class/identifier/ect) and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` (<kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> using Default keymap).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/viewing-inline-documentation.html

---

If you want this documentation window **to be always visible** -- just pin it (using Pin icon in top right corner). It will show the info on most recently invoked element.

If you want this info **to be automatically updated** for the element that is currently focused (based on caret position) -- activate `Auto-update from Source` option there.

---

If you want this documentation window **to appear automatically on mouse hover** -- activate `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Show quick documentation on mouse move` option (delay is configurable).

Comment: Is it also possible to configure it like in netbeans so that it only shows on mouse over + holding CTRL? That would be great.

Comment: AFAIK -- No. Found these tickets (they seem related): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156484 ; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164821 -- watch them (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: The only alternative I know to have it working on Ctrl+Hover -- Pin the `Quick Documentation` window (so it's always visible) and Ctrl+Hover will update it without the need to move the caret there.